# How to change libav decoding framerate?

Tags: c++, decoding, frame-rate, libav

Is there any way to change libav decoding frame rate? There are several variables in libav structures responsible for getting frame rate but as I know these all are for reading purposes only (in decoding mode). Among them are:

```
AVStream.duration
AVStream.nb_frames
AVStream.r_frame_rate
AVStream.time_base
```

The former two tell me the number of frames, and the latter two tell me the frame rate. But it seems that I can't just set them or it won't probably cause proper effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need the decoded video at a lower framerate than it was encoded. The best solution would be to skip the frame packets before decoding them, at the rate you need (before calling avcodec_decode_video2()). Never tried it, but it should work. This will save unnecesary CPU spent for decoding frames you do not need.

Comment: I need to be able not only to decrease but also to increase framerate. Moreover many codecs use truncated flag so frames can be shifted in packets - it's not certainly that one packet will contain one frame. So skipping packets obviously can and surely will cause problems. In addition video stream can contain some info packets (usually in begin of stream) despite there are some separated data streams. So it's not the best idea if you want to write code for supporting multiple formats.